# jQuery keyup function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, keyup, eventtrigger

I am trying to activate `keyup` event on an input element, the problem is it didn't trigger once I press a key, I have to do another key event to activate it, which is not normal!

Here's my code:

```
$(".conv").keyup(function(){
    var itemId = new Array();
    
    $(".itemId").each(function() {
        itemId.push($(this).text());
    });

    if (itemId.length == 0 || isEmpty($(this).val())) {
        $(this).val('0.00');
        return false;
    }

    if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
        alert("Only numeric values are allowed in '" + $(this).parent().parent().find('th').text() + "' field.");
        return false;
    }

    calcShipping();
});
```

I tried to use `on` like this, but also not working:

```
$('body').on("keyup", ".plus", function(){
    var itemId = new Array();

    $(".itemId").each(function() {
        itemId.push($(this).text());
    });

    if (itemId.length == 0) {
        $(this).val('0.00');
        return false;
    }

    calcShipping();
});
```

Calculate shipping function:

```
var calcShipping = function() {

    if (isEmpty($(".totalCost2").text())) {
        $(".totalCost2").text(parseInt($(".totalCost").text()));
    }

    var plus      = 0;
    var conv      = parseInt($(".conv").val());
    var tCost     = parseInt($(".totalCost2").text());
    var tQty      = 0;
    var tFinal    = 0;
    var tLast     = 0;
    var qty       = 0;
    var totalCost = 0;
    var cost      = new Array();
    var qtyCost   = new Array();

    $("#txtItems2").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("#btnReset2").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("#uploadItems").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $("#startUpload").attr('disabled','disabled');

    $(".plus").each(function(){
        if (isEmpty($(this).val())) {
            $(this).val('0.00');
        }
        if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
            alert("Only numeric values are allowed in '" + $(this).parent().parent().find('th').text() + "' field.");
            return false;
        }
        plus += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $(".qty").each(function() {
        qtyCost.push(parseInt($(this).text()));
        tQty += parseInt($(this).text());
    });

    $(".cost").each(function() {
        cost.push($(this).text());
    });

    tFinal = plus + tCost;
    tLast  = tFinal/tQty;
    
    var qty = 0;

    $(".cost").each(function(){
      qty = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find($(".qty")).text());
      $(this).text(tLast * qty * conv);
      qty = 0;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < cost.length; i++)
    {
        totalCost += (cost[i] * qtyCost[i]);
    }

    $(".totalCost").text(totalCost.toFixed(2));
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8ukL69r3/ Of course the logic in the event doesn't work since I am lacking other parts of your code, but the event fires as it is supposed to.

Comment: I see it's normally working alone, but for my piece of code it's not!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You can not just dump all your code. Please read [MCVE]. You need to provide a *minimal* example.

Comment: It sounds like you have a syntax error somewhere in your code. I would recommend you to use a [syntax checker](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+syntax+checker):

Comment: @Anders I did checked my code and its syntax is valid already.

Comment: I posed the function code because one of the helpers told me to do, to make things clear too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94033/discussion-between-anders-and-cairocoder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I have to recalculate the ".cost" after modifying it, not before, like this:

```
$(".cost").each(function(){
      qty = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().find($(".qty")).text());
      var newCost = tLast * qty * conv;
      $(this).text(newCost);
      qty = 0;
});

$(".cost").each(function() {
    cost.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('.conv').on("input", function() {
    //do what you need to do here
});
```

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1u0eusat/)

Comment: Same problem, I have to press another key!